# Unable to get value of selected mat radio button with *ngFor Angular 11

Tags: angular, forms, angular-material, radio-button

TEMPLATE:

```
<form [formgroup]="radioForm">
<mat-radio-group>
<mat-radio-button *ngFor="let list of lists" formControlName="list" value="list.num">{{list.name}}
</mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
</form>
```

TS file:

```
radioForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
   list: new FormControl(),
});

list: List[]=[];
num: any;

ngOninit(){
  this.list = this.template.lists;
}
```

list array in console contains three values... name, color and num.

On selection of radio button I want the num value from the list.. How can I achieve that?

Comment: use square brackets here `[value]="list.num"`

Comment: I get num value as null when I do.. this.num = this.radioForm.controls.list.value

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 bugs to fix:

`value="list.num"` means the value of the radio button is a string named "list.num".
You need to add brackets to bind the property with `[value]="list.num"`

The *formControlName* directive must be used on the `mat-radio-group` tag, not on every `mat-radio-button` ones.

Comment: I did what you suggested but I am still getting num value as null when I do.. this.num = this.radioForm.controls.list.value in ngOninit

Comment: By doing it on ngOnInit, it happens before any interaction with the browser so no radio button has been selected yet

Comment: then How do I know what got selected.. should i create a method outside and then call it in ngOninit?

Comment: At the time the user will submit the form with the completed value, you call a related function to do whatever you want. If it's about getting direct changes for you, you can use this code sample in ngOnInit to log form changes: `this.radioForm.valueChanges.subscribe(console.log)`